# Why do I get an error code shows (PHP Warning)

Tags: php, preg-match, warnings

my problem :

```
PHP Warning:  preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in *****
```

my code :

```
foreach ($_POST as $secvalue) {
  if ((preg_match("/<[^>]*iframe*\"?[^>]*/", $secvalue)) ||
  (preg_match("/<[^>]*object*\"?[^>]*/", $secvalue)) ||
  (preg_match("/<[^>]*applet*\"?[^>]*/", $secvalue)) ||
  (preg_match("/<[^>]*meta*\"?[^>]*/", $secvalue)) ||
  (preg_match("/<[^>]*onmouseover*\"?[^>]*/", $secvalue)) ||
  (preg_match("/<[^>]script*\"?[^>]*/", $secvalue)) ||
  (preg_match("/<[^>]*body*\"?[^>]*/", $secvalue)) ||
  (preg_match("/<[^>]style*\"?[^>]*/", $secvalue))) {
   die ($htmltags);
  }
 }
}
```

whats problem ? and What is the correct code?
tanks

Comment: show what are you getting in `$_POST`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your passing an array as a second argument to `preg_match()`, But `preg_match()` will take second argument as a String value.

Check the bellow code that will get all key value from the post request.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $secvalue){
 if ((preg_match("/<[^>]*iframe*\"?[^>]*/", $secvalue)) ||
  (preg_match("/<[^>]*object*\"?[^>]*/", $secvalue)) ||
  (preg_match("/<[^>]*applet*\"?[^>]*/", $secvalue)) ||
  (preg_match("/<[^>]*meta*\"?[^>]*/", $secvalue)) ||
  (preg_match("/<[^>]*onmouseover*\"?[^>]*/", $secvalue)) ||
  (preg_match("/<[^>]script*\"?[^>]*/", $secvalue)) ||
  (preg_match("/<[^>]*body*\"?[^>]*/", $secvalue)) ||
  (preg_match("/<[^>]style*\"?[^>]*/", $secvalue))) {
   die ($htmltags);
  }
 }
```

Comment: i try it , but i have warrning again :"PHP Warning:  preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in..."